# MS Excel VBA: Find cells that have a specific formula type

Tags: excel, vba

I want to automatically find cells that contain formulas only being a simple reference. For example:

`=D20` or `='Sheet1'!D20`.

The purpose is that I want to automatically color code these cells.

Is there a way in VBA to search for formula types?

Comment: Have You tried Range.HasFormula ?

Comment: Use that suggested method with a Like operator to find formulas that match your search patterns

Comment: Look for cells that only have a single `Precedent` range, and match their `Formula` against a regex or like pattern.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon got a point. Due to the fact you can have all sort of cell references, RexEx might be your best bet (in combination with the `Like` operator). I tried to write a code that will do that in an efficient way (see below)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some time to let this sink in, I think it's not that straightforward. Direct cell references can include simple references like:

```
=A1
```

But there are instances where you can refer to another cell in another sheet, another opened workbook and even another closed workbook. While this makes it difficult to use `RIGHT`, `LEFT` functions or even `FORMULATEXT` for the likes, the one thing that you can do is to check for patterns.

Any direct cell reference cannot include any other calculation, meaning it must exclude any unwanted operater (/,*,-,+). As far as I'm concerned this means that if we check a cell that only has ONE [`Precedent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.precedents), the formula can NOT start with a digit NOR can it end with digits after any of the above mentioned operators.

Our best bet here, is to put these criteria in a regular expression. I'm by no mean a RegEx expert, but I think the following does the trick:

```
"^=.*[A-Z]+\$*\d+$"
```

- Start of the line is `=`
- Followed by any word/non-word character, 0-n times
- End of the line must be digits, 1-n times, preceded by either just upper case alfabetic characters or a combination with the dollar sign (for absolute cell references)

The above works as long as we include a check for just one `.Precedent` and a check if the second character of the formula isn't numeric. The code example would then, for example, look like:

```
Sub FindFormualaType()

Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, cl As Range
Dim regex As New RegExp
Dim matches As Object
Dim tststr As String

With regex
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = "^=.*[A-Z]+\$*\d+$"
End With

With Sheet1 'Change to your sheet's codename
    Set rng1 = Intersect(.Cells, .Cells.SpecialCells(-4123))
    For Each cl In rng1
        On Error Resume Next
        If cl.Precedents.Count = 1 Then
            If Left(cl.Formula, 2) Like "=#" = False Then
                Set matches = regex.Execute(cl.Formula)
                If matches.Count = 1 Then
                    If Not rng2 Is Nothing Then
                        Set rng2 = Union(rng2, cl)
                    Else
                        Set rng2 = cl
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next cl
End With

rng2.Interior.Color = vbGreen

End Sub
```

To explain some of the steps in the code above:

- To use the `RegExp` you have to set a reference to it:

  [image]
- The code then makes use of [`.SpecialCells`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.specialcells) with [`xlCellTypeFormulas`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlcelltype) (`-4123`), and creates a `.Range` object through [`.Intersect`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.intersect). Therefore we don't have to loop all cells to check with [`.HasFormula`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.hasformula) (hopefully saving some time).
- Next up is the loop through all cells in that newly created `.Range` object and check if `Precendents.Count = 1`. We need to capsule that into an `On Error Resume Next` because it would error out if no precedents are found, e.g.: a formula like `="Hello"`.
- When the count equals 1, we check with the [`Like`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/like-operator) operator if we can savely execute the regex and test for a match on the used pattern.
- Because I would rather do a fill operation in one go, I suggest to create another `.Range` object (rng2) and use [`Union`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.union) to set this object.
- Finally we can use something like `rng2.Interior.Color = vbGreen` to color all cells that just have a direct reference to just one cell.

Hope that helped. By no means I'm an RegEx expert and it can probably be done simpler.

---

Some background information on why I used the `Like` operator. Because I wanted to be sure no calculation is done with the cell reference, the first character in the equation can NOT be numeric. Within RegEx you got something called "lookahead". Though, unfortunately, I couldn't get the expression to work withing VBA (unsupported?) and therefor used the `Like` operator to make sure the second character was not numeric.

Comment: ...unless an accountant made the sheet, then it's `=+F23` and all the patterns go out the window...  +1 for the effort though =)

Comment: @MathieuGuindon, I am unfamiliar with what the `=+` does for accounting. To me it looks like it's not the same as a simple cell reference asked for by OP but actually some kind of calculation. Could you elaborate? Thanks for the kudo's ;)

Comment: lol it does nothing, it's just something I noticed in accountants' worksheets, they do cell refs with a `+` just to mess with people trying to parse their formulas haha

Comment: @MathieuGuindon, in that case it would just mean another Like operator imo and this case would also be dealt with, right? Along the line of: `"=+#"`

Comment: The reason accountants use =+ is that it allows for easy entry using the numpad. After entry + becomes =+.

Answer (score 1):

Use `FORMULATEXT()` function in `Conditional Formatting` to highlight automatically cells that contains your formula. See below formula for `Conditional Formatting`

```
=OR(FORMULATEXT(A1)="=Sheet1!D20",FORMULATEXT(A1)="=D20")
```

[image]

Comment: For Excel prior to 2016, it is a trivial matter to create a `FormulaText` UDF. However, this does mean having a VBA-enabled worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

Create a loop to go through all cells with formulas (.HasFormula), get the formula text of the cell as a string, take all formulatext except the first character (RIGHT( text, (LEN(text) - 1))) and then test if that string is a valid Range. If it's not, then there is more in the cell then 'just a simple reference'. Good luck with figuring out the code :)

Comment: I don’t think this solution deals with all the different intricacies unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7PbB.png)This is an old question, but I think there may be an easier solution that nearly solves the original question that hasn't been mentioned here. At work I occasionally run into issues when one or more cells in a table have been hard entered, while the rest link to another dataset. If the corresponding data that's been hard coded has changed, the totals on the table I'm using will wrong. Instead of programming, I simply use "cntrl f" to search for one of the components of the formula that should be there, and replace that component with the same text, but use formatting to highlight the text (make sure you're searching in "formula" and not text) The result easily shows which cells have the formula, and which do not. If your data is formatted as a table, or just has a data filter, you can sort by that color to quickly group the cells that need reworked. For me, this has been a huge time saver. I routinely work with worksheets that have 20K lines, so being able to find, sort, and repair issues with hard entries is a lifesaver. Doesn't exactly answer the Q, but it's close!

Comment: Hi Richard thanks for your answer. That would indeed also be an option, albeit not automated like VBA

Comment: Some paragraphs would help.